# JSF update jQuery Expression

Tags: jquery, jsf

I've got an DataTable and I want to show a lightbox with an row specific image by context menu item.

bean.contextMedia is the row object on which the context menu is called. The following code updates the contextMedia:

```
<p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{jcloud.onRowContextMenu}" global="false" />
```

And here I use the value:

```
<p:contextMenu for="mediaForm:mediaDT">
    <p:menuitem value="show image"
        oncomplete="jQuery('##{bean.contextMedia.uiId}').trigger('click');" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

**Now to the problem:** The jQuery expression gets "compiled" when the page loads. That means when I update the `contextMedia` at the bean using ajax, the jQuery expression is out of date. The statement is kind of constant. When I reload the page, the expression gets "recompiled".

I also tried to update the `menuitem` with the jQuery expression in it. The result was that the menuitem disappeared from the context menu.

The lightbox is defined at the begin of the `<h:body>` with `style="display:none;"` and `uiId` as id for all the visible image files at the DataTable.

Comment: do you mean that when you right click a row and select an option from the context menu, a light box component with an image is displayed. but the selected context menu option is lost, ie after execution of contextmenu listener , the selected option is lost..is this correct??

Comment: No,  the content of the bean is correct, only the jQuery command doesn't call the getter for the value after it has changed, it gets only called after page reload. not after each click in the context menu...